# FullCalendar disappears from Razor page when adding Events

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core, fullcalendar, razor-pages

I have this code on my index.cshtml page:

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridWeek'
            events: @Html.Raw(ViewData["Events"])
        });
        calendar.render();
    });

</script>
```

and this on the index.cshtml.cs page:

```
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Hour = await _context.Hour
            .Select(hour => new Hour
            {
                StartTime = hour.StartTime,
                EndTime = hour.EndTime
            })
            .ToListAsync();

        var events = Hour.Select(hour => new
        {
            title = "Work",
            start = hour.StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
            end = hour.EndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
        }).ToList();

        ViewData["Events"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(events);
    }
```

I've tested the Events string by printing it on the web page and it prints correctly, it comes from the database in json format, but for some reason it doesn't work with FullCalendar.

When I take out "events: @Html.Raw(ViewData["Events"])" from the calendar script, the calendar displays on the page, but when I add it, the calendar disappears completely. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I'm a complete newbie with ASP.NET. This is just my own project that I'm doing in order to understand how this all works.

Comment: "When I take out "events: @Html.Raw(ViewData["Events"])" from the calendar script, the calendar displays on the page, but when I add it, the calendar disappears completely." Have you checked the console for errors? F12 should bring up developer tools, and click 'Console' tab.

Comment: I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'events'"

Comment: You have a simple syntax error in the JS: `initialView: 'dayGridWeek'` is missing the `,` from the end. In a JS object, property declarations need a `,` to separate each declaration from the previous one.

Comment: It was the darned comma, thank you for pointing it out!